# Difficulty in accessing data of 2 API Using ForkJoin to access

Tags: json, angular, api, fork-join

I am trying to access 2 API on my angular application

1. https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/api/odds/v1/leagues/3/offers/gamelines.json
2. https://www.fantasylabs.com/api/sportevents/3/2019_06_17

I am using forkjoin to access data of both data asynchronously

Here is my code for api.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mlb-api',
  templateUrl: './mlb-api.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mlb-api.component.css']
})
export class MlbApiComponent  {

loadedCharacter: {};
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let character = this.http.get('https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/api/odds/v1/leagues/3/offers/gamelines.json');
    let characterHomeworld = this.http.get('https://www.fantasylabs.com/api/sportevents/3/2019_06_17');

    forkJoin([character, characterHomeworld]).subscribe(results => {

      (results[0] as any).name = results[1];
      this.loadedCharacter = results[0];
    });
  }
}
```

I am trying to achieve name property from 1st API and EventID property from 2nd API.

Here is my html code.

```
   <td>{{loadedCharacter.name}}</td>
    <td>{{loadedCharacter.EventId}}</td>
```

In the output I am getting

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

I am able to retrieve all json data on page using this command

```
{{loadedCharacter | json}}
```

What changes should I make so that I can be able to retrieve all data individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your code like this:

Have the `loadCharcters` like this:

```
loadedCharacter: {name: string, eventId: string} = <{name: string, eventId: string}>{};

ngOnInit() {
    let character = this.http.get('https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/api/odds/v1/leagues/3/offers/gamelines.json')
    .pipe(map((re: any) => re.events));
    let characterHomeworld = this.http.get('https://www.fantasylabs.com/api/sportevents/3/2019_06_17');

    forkJoin([character, characterHomeworld]).subscribe(results => {

      this.loadedCharacter.name = results[0][0].name;
      this.loadedCharacter.EventId = results[1][0].EventId;
      console.log(results[0][0].name);
    });
  }

<td>{{loadedCharacter.name}}</td>
<td>{{loadedCharacter.EventId}}</td>
```

I have updated the stackblitz.

See the demo in stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8npc19?file=app/button-overview-example.ts

Comment: Then what should I write in html file to access them?

Comment: @Karan See the updated answer and check the same in stackblitz.

Comment: What if I want to loop over name and display all?

Comment: @Karan if you want to see all names then - `const allNames = results[0].map(r => r.name);
      console.log(allNames);`

Comment: Should I add `<ng-container *ngFor="let data of allNames">
<td>{{data.name}}</td>
</ng-container>` in html file? To display on the page?

Comment: Yes, you can. I have updated stackblitz to show the names coming in next line. `<ng-container *ngFor="let n of allNames">
  <div>{{n}}</div>
</ng-container>`

Comment: For accessing label I am using  `this.loadedCharacter.label = results[1].label;
` which returns undefined. Could you help?

Comment: `label` property is in `offers` array of `result[0][0]`. You need to access `label` like this - this.loadedCharacter.label = result[0][0].offers[0]. NOTE - You can get all labels similar to names

Comment: Also you can use https://jsoneditoronline.org/ to see how your json data is structured. Just copy paste your json output and format it in the website. It will show the formatted json data

Comment: I have tried the approach you said, it still gives undefined - I have added in the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dof68u

Comment: @Karan See the updated stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8npc19?file=app/button-overview-example.ts

Comment: Hey it worked but I did not understand why did you use .flat().map()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195207/discussion-between-user2216584-and-karan).

Comment: Hey friend one more problem, if you are free to check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672586/accessing-data-from-2-api-simultaneously-using-forkjoin-not-defined-error?noredirect=1#comment99914518_56672586

Comment: @Karan responded in your SO question. Please check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The results[1] is an array returned by the request to https://www.fantasylabs.com/api/sportevents/3/2019_06_17

On the other hand, the result of the first one is an object with only one property "events" so I think you should think a bit more about this mapping:

```js
...
      (results[0] as any).name = results[1];
      this.loadedCharacter = results[0];
...
```

Comment: Could you give some more clarity?