# Accessing data from 2 API simultaneously using ForkJoin : Not Defined error

Tags: json, angular, api, fork-join

Using ForkJoin I am trying to access data from 2 API

https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/api/odds/v1/leagues/3/offers/gamelines.json

https://www.fantasylabs.com/api/sportevents/3/2019_06_17

I am using forkjoin to access data of both data asynchronously. I am able to access  homeTeamName, awayTeamName successfully, but while access lines i am getting error

```
core.js:1521 ERROR ReferenceError: allline is not defined
```

api.component.html

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">




<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table summary="This table shows how to create responsive tables using Bootstrap's default functionality" class="table table-bordered table-hover">

          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Information</th>
              <th>HomeTeam vs AwayTeam</th>
              <th>Line</th>


            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                  <ng-container *ngFor="let n of allhomeTeamName">
                    <tr><td>{{n}}</td></tr>
                  </ng-container>


                </tbody>

                <tbody>
            <tr>

              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                  <ng-container *ngFor="let n of allawayTeamName">
                    <tr><td>{{n}}</td></tr>
                  </ng-container>


                </tbody>



                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                  <ng-container *ngFor="let n of allline">
                    <tr><td>{{n}}</td></tr>
                  </ng-container>


                </tbody>



                </div>
              </div>
```

api.component.ts code

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mlb-api',
  templateUrl: './mlb-api.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mlb-api.component.css']
})
export class MlbApiComponent  {
 loadedCharacter: {  homeTeamName:string, awayTeamName:string, line:string, EventId:string, visitorTeam:string,homeTeam:string} = <{homeTeamName:string, awayTeamName:string, line:string, EventId:string, visitorTeam:string,homeTeam:string}>{};
    allhomeTeamName;
  allawayTeamName;
  allline;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let character = this.http.get('https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/api/odds/v1/leagues/3/offers/gamelines.json')
    .pipe(map((re: any) => re.events));
    let characterHomeworld = this.http.get('https://www.fantasylabs.com/api/sportevents/3/2019_06_17');

    forkJoin([character, characterHomeworld]).subscribe(results => {

      //(results[0] as any).name = results[1];
      //this.loadedCharacter.name = results[0].name;
      this.loadedCharacter.homeTeamName = results[0].homeTeamName;
      this.loadedCharacter.awayTeamName = results[0].awayTeamName;
     this.loadedCharacter.line = results[0][0].offers[0].outcomes[0].line;
     //this.loadedCharacter.line = results[1][0].VisitorTeam;
     //this.loadedCharacter.line = results[1][0].HomeTeam;

      //this.loadedCharacter.EventId = results[1][0].EventId[1];

      this.allNames = results[0].map(r => r.name);
      console.log(this.allNames);

      this.allhomeTeamName = results[0].map(r => r.homeTeamName);
      console.log(this.allhomeTeamName);

       this.allawayTeamName = results[0].map(r => r.awayTeamName);
      console.log(this.allawayTeamName);

       this.allline = results[0].map(r=>r.offers).flat().map(r => r.outcomes).flat().map(o => o.line);
       console.log(allline);




       this.allEventId = results[1].map(r => r.EventId);
      console.log(results[1][0]);

      this.allvisitorTeam = results[0].map(r => r.VisitorTeam);
      console.log(this.allvisitorTeam);

      this.allawayTeam = results[0].map(r => r.AwayTeam);
      console.log( this.allawayTeam);

    });
  }
}
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What do you get if you do `console.log(results[1][0])`? Inspect the result set and see how it's structured.

Comment: It gives `{EventDetails: null, EventId: 4436180, SportId: 3, VisitorTeam: "Tampa Bay Rays", HomeTeam: "New York Yankees", …}` But I it give undefined if i try to access the data using       `this.loadedCharacter.EventId = results[1][0].EventId;
`

Comment: I figured out EventId, can you check for label?

Comment: label? I don't see anything relates to label.

Comment: I have updated my code, I have difficulty displaying line on my page

Comment: Just a suggestion: with forkJoin, you can replace the results in your subscribe with `([draftKingResults, fantasyLabsResults])`, so that you dont have to do that `results[0]` nonsense. Looks much more readable.

Comment: Do I need to declare them first? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your code like this -

```
ngOnInit() {

    let character = this.http.get('https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/api/odds/v1/leagues/3/offers/gamelines.json')
    .pipe(map((re: any) => re.events));
    let characterHomeworld = this.http.get('https://www.fantasylabs.com/api/sportevents/3/2019_06_17');

    forkJoin([character, characterHomeworld]).subscribe(([draftkingsResp, fantasylabsResp]) => {      

      this.allNames = draftkingsResp.map(r => r.name);
      //console.log(this.allNames);

      this.allhomeTeamName = draftkingsResp.map(r => r.homeTeamName);
      //console.log(this.allhomeTeamName);

       this.allawayTeamName = draftkingsResp.map(r => r.awayTeamName);
      //console.log(this.allawayTeamName);

       this.alllabel = draftkingsResp.map(r => r.offers).flat().map(o => o.label);
      //console.log(this.alllabel);

      this.allline = draftkingsResp.map(r=>r.offers).flat().map(r => r.outcomes).flat().map(o => o.line);
       console.log(this.allline);
      //this.allline will have 'undefined' as well
      //if you want then you can filter
      this.allline = this.allline.filter(l => !!l);
      console.log(this.allline);
    });
  }
```

See the stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8npc19?file=app%2Fbutton-overview-example.ts

Comment: Seriously, genius!!

Comment: Hey friend one issue which accessing data - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56740175/bootstrap-table-displaying-columns-using-ngfor . If you are free to check. Thanks

Comment: @Karan I think your question is already answered by the time I saw it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56758807/cannot-access-specific-json-data-from-api